# CSS Flexbox - Align the contents on top and align the button to bottom

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to modify an existing component which inherits the **Flexbox concept**.

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

Now what I'm trying to achieve is regardless of content size inside the box:

1. The box will have the same height - aligned to each other
2. The button will stay at the bottom even if the top contents are long.

Here is the existing structure that I'm trying to fix:

```
<section class="container counsellor-list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 mb-30 counsellor-list-item">
      <div class="state_chosen">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1771835/1477/i/950/depositphotos_14779771-stock-photo-portrait-of-confident-young-doctor.jpg" />
          <div class="bg-blue20 p-30 counsellor-list-item-content">
              <div class="text-coral subtitle-small text-bold text-uppercase mb-24 d-flex flex-wrap">
              <span class="">
                  Wien
              </span>
              <span class="ml-16">
                  St. Polten
              </span>
              <span class="ml-auto language">
                  <span>
                  DE
                  <span> | </span>
                  EN
                  </span>
              </span>
              </div>
              <h2 class="mb-24">Jan Faustio</h2>
              <div class="">
              <a class="btn btn-coral" href="#"> Button </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ...
</section>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/russel-fermin/pen/MWQmVYx)

I tried a lot of stuff but didn't work as I'm expecting it to be/result.

Comment: Even if codepen is a valid link, please post a working example here.

Comment: Why can't you add a height on the lower part of the card where the name and text is? It won't be nice if it has for example content but has squeezed paddings or scroll on some and not others anyway.

Comment: Then you add max characters and provide ellipses if it goes over x amount of characters or lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, I hope I understood what you want to achieve https://codepen.io/IvanBisultanov/pen/PoQmXqX

I also added .btn-wrap classname, and wrapped all HTML above in div

```
.counsellor-list-item-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.btn-wrap {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```